# what is the difference between map.every and map.any in groovy?

Tags: methods, groovy, dictionary

I just want to ask the main difference between these two methods. And what does it mean when the groovy API says predicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short explanation:

- a predicate is a function/expression that returns a boolean value
- map.every returns true only if the predicate evaluates to true for all elements
- map.any returns true if the predicate evaluates to true for at least one element

Example (pseudocode):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.every { |x| x < 3 } => false, since 3,4 and 5 are not smaller than 3
a.any   { |x| x < 3 } => true, since 1 and 2 are smaller than 3
```

Comment: hey bro, thanks for the answer. do they really have to come up with a new term to call a function that returns boolean? anyway man, thanks again.

Comment: @simon The term predicate to define a [function that returns true or false based on its parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29#Simplified_overview) isn't a new term...  It's been around for quite a while ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates oh really? dang, I made a fool of myself didn't I? :D But I do believe it wasn't that used too much when I was learning Java. anyway, thanks for the tip :D

Comment: @simon no worries :-) And you didn't make a fool of yourself, so no worries there either ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation;

[Map.any says](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#any%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

> Iterates over the entries of a map, and checks whether a predicate is valid for **at least one entry**

Wheras [Map.every says](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#every%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

> Iterates over the entries of a map, and checks whether a predicate is valid for **all entries**.

By *predicate* it means it runs the entry through the closure and checks the result for Groovy Truthiness

Example (expanding Frank's pseudocode to actual groovy code with a Map):

```
a = [a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4]
assert a.every { key, value -> value < 3 } == false // since 3 and 4 are not smaller than 3
assert a.any   { key, value -> value < 3 } == true  // since 1 and 2 are smaller than 3
```